# Linux command works on terminal but not in ipython notebook

Tags: postgresql, macos, shell, jupyter-notebook

I am running `pg_dump mydb > ~/Desktop/mydb.dump` on my mac shell which works perfectly fine.

But when i use the same command on jupyter notebook with **!** or **%%bash**, it doesn't work, saying that `/bin/sh: pg_dump: command not found`

I do not have any problem with running other commands on notebook.

What could be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT & ANSWER:**

so, even though i am running jupyter notebook via terminal, interestingly the env variables are not the same it seems like.

i do not know why exactly but instead of pg_dump, if i write the whole path for pg_dump, which i added to ~/.bash_profile on terminal, it works on jupyter notebook as well. in my case it is

`/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/11/bin/pg_dump mydb > ~/Desktop/mydb.dump`

Comment: In one case the `pg_dump` executable is contained in one of the directories in the `PATH` environment variable, in the other case not.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your $PATH variable when you use bash in ipython notebook
Like:

```
 export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/pg_dump && pg_dump mydb > ~/Desktop/mydb.dump
```

Comment: i added that but nothing changed. :/